# Libcurl Write_data is being called multiple-times leading to truncated data in buffer

Tags: python, c, http, libcurl

I have a python server running on my desktop that parsers a large CSV file and sends each row to an embedded device in response to a HTTP request as cjson file setup like so which can be received just fine when I test it on the samedevice using a C program but fails when I try to run the same code on an embedded Linux ubuntu device. The code compiles and all data is send from the server appropriately but issues arise with the recived data being randomly missing values

```
self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
            self.send_header('Content-Encoding', 'chunked')  # Specify gzip encoding
            self.end_headers()
            response_data = self.read_csv_lines(param_value)
            response_json = json.dumps(response_data)

        # Compress the JSON data
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='w') as f:
            f.write(response_json.encode('utf-8'))
        compressed_data = buf.getvalue()

        # Send the compressed JSON response
        self.wfile.write(compressed_data)
```

Here is my C code for sending responses as well as handling the incoming data.

'''

```
size_t write_callback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    char *data = (char *)userp;

    // Append the received data to the user buffer
    memcpy(data, curl_buffer, realsize);

    return realsize;
}

void readDatasetLineByLine(CURL* curl ,CURLcode res ,int line_number){

// Read float values from file

float value;

char url_query[50];
sprintf(url_query,"http://192.168.137.1:8080?param=%d",line_number);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url_query);

// Set the callback function to handle received data
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);

// Create a buffer to store the received data
// Perform the HTTP request
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

test_input_memory[0] = value;
 if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    } else {
        // Print the received text
        cJSON *root = cJSON_Parse(curl_buffer);
        if (root != NULL) {
            // Check if the root is an array
            if (cJSON_IsArray(root)) {
                // Iterate through the array and print the float values
                int count = 0;
                cJSON *value;
                cJSON_ArrayForEach(value, root) {
                    if (cJSON_IsNumber(value)) {
                        test_input_memory[count] = (float)value->valuedouble;
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Free cJSON objects
            cJSON_Delete(root);                
        } 
        else 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing JSON\n");
        }
}
```

What i'm finding most curious is that the write_callback function runs multiple times randomly splitting up some responses but leaving others whole in a way that shows no obvious pattern. How do I get the entire response copied without any errors or missing values ?

Comment: What have you done to try debugging this code? Did you verify that your server works by visiting it in a normal browser? Did you verify that your client works by requesting other JSON-based APIs? Knowing which environment contains the error would be extremely useful.

Comment: This comment `// Append the received data to the user buffer` indicates that you want to add something to the existing buffer. But `memcpy(data, curl_buffer, realsize);` just copies to the same location again and again. For appending you would need to store number of bytes copied so far and then copy at an updated location. You might also need the total number of bytes for terminating that buffer before parsing as a JSON string.

Comment: For testing you could add some `printf` to your callback showing what data is provided in each call. Mind the terminating 0 byte you need for printing string but which is probably not part of your incoming data.

Comment: I have tested it by running the same code and iterating  the function over various values of the param. It functions fine when run on the computer itself that's hosting the server but when I run it on an embedded device the received data is inexplicably missing certain values and is truncated

Comment: How did you verify that? The code does not print data from each call but only uses the buffer after the request was completed. If you run it in a debugger, where did you stop the code to inspect data?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, the issue was that my write_callback function did not have support for being called multiple time by the same response as I was unaware of this behaviour being possible. By modifying it to keep track of an offset when the res get's broken up into multiple interactions I was able to keep the code working regardless of how lib-curl split up each request.

Comment: If you think about downloading a 10TB file you would need to store everything in RAM if you were not able to call your callback function multible times. Splitting transmissions is very fundamental. You should always be prepared to get smaller junks and keep track of collecting all parts. This applies also for reading/wrinting to a file etc.